# How to connect data from database from different tables for asp dropdownlist?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Here My question is How to connect different data tabels either 2 or more tables from single database and has to come for dropdownlist in asp.net page??
I am trying a lot but its not working please help??

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research effort.  If you've attempted something please *post what you've tried*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some help, at least so your effort, or what is your progress.

Depend on how do you handle Dropdownlist and your SQL, you can have several alternative way to do. But the point is joining all tables together and feed it to your dropdownlist.